# SQL how to select most viewed products

Tags: sql, select

I need to select customers with the products that they viewed the most. I tried  using 'group by' and 'order by' statements but I guess incorectly. anybody can help please?

please see an example below:

[image: please see an example below]

Comment: What is your schema? I don't see anything related to products on those tables in the image.

Comment: Poor table design. Don't store email and first name over and over again.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie? (I.e. two different product have been viewed the same, most number of times.)

Comment: sku is a product code.

Comment: its not a typical database. its a salesforce's data extension and sql there is pretty limited

Answer (score 0):

First aggregate using `count()` to get the counts. Then you can use `row_number()` to identify the (a) row with the largest count for a user.

```
SELECT y.id,
       y.email,
       y.firstname,
       y.sku
       FROM (SELECT x.id,
                    x.email,
                    x.firstname,
                    x.sku,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.id,
                                                    x.email,
                                                    x.firstname
                                       ORDER BY x.views DESC) rn
                    FROM (SELECT t.id,
                                 t.email,
                                 t.firstname,
                                 t.sku,
                                 count(*) views
                                 FROM elbat t
                                 GROUP BY t.id,
                                          t.firstname,
                                          t.sku) x) y
       WHERE y.rn = 1;
```

Of course, your DBMS must support `row_number()` for this to work. And you didn't mention you DBMS, so I don't know, if that's the case.

Comment: every additional row in a table is a product view. so the view is reflected by SKU

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select id, email, firstname, sku
from (select id, email, firstname, sku, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*)) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, email, firstname, sku
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: syntax error. i dont think salesforce supports row_number;/

Comment: @consultant46 . . . `row_number()` is an ISO/ANSI standard function.  You have not specified the database you are using, but most support this functionality.